# List element length bumps Bootstrap column to next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying some search results using an unordered list inside a bootstrap grid.  In Bootstrap 3 the columns would stay inline, but upgrading to Bootstrap 4 now the search result column (div id="all-results") falls below the first column IF the search result title is too long.

I made 2 examples on codepen.

In this one, only a short search result is returned and the columns remain inline: https://codepen.io/xanabobana/pen/rNLVEba

In this codepen, a longer title is returned and the column drops down: https://codepen.io/xanabobana/pen/pobRxpx

How do I make sure the long search result doesn't break the column?

Code with the longer search result:

```
<section class="main-width container"><h1>Data Archive Search Results</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav id="leftnav" class="sortBar closed">
            <h3 class="spacing">Filter Results</h3>

            <ul class='sortButtons'>
                 <li class='subnavli'><a id="all-head" class="all-result-head activeCategory">All Results (19)</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
            <li class="navli-toplevel">Type</li>
            <a id="clearTypeFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
            <ul id="type" class='sortButtons type'>
                        <li class='subnavli'><a id="project" class="result-head">Projects (6)</a></li>
                        <li class='subnavli'><a id="dataset" class="result-head">Datasets (12)</a></li>
                        <li class='subnavli'><a id="document" class="result-head">Documents (0)</a></li>
                        <li class='subnavli'><a id="person" class="result-head">People (1)</a></li>
                        <li class='subnavli'><a id="news" class="result-head">News (0)</a></li>                
                        <li class='subnavli'><a id="event" class="result-head">Events (0)</a></li>    
            </ul>

            <li class="navli-toplevel">Themes</li>
            <a id="clearThemeFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
            <ul id="allTheme" class="sortButtons themes"><li data-theme="forest" class="subnavli"><a>Forest (3)</a></li><li data-theme="water" class="subnavli"><a>Water (2)</a></li><li data-theme="soil" class="subnavli"><a>Soil (1)</a></li><li data-theme="air" class="subnavli"><a>Air (1)</a></li></ul>            <li class="navli-toplevel">Tags</li>
            <a id="clearTagFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
            <ul id="allTags" class="sortButtons filterTags"><li data-tag="foliar nitrogen" class="subnavli"><a>Foliar nitrogen (6)</a></li><li data-tag="ponds" class="subnavli"><a>Ponds (4)</a></li><li data-tag="biology" class="subnavli"><a>Biology (3)</a></li><li data-tag="water chemistry" class="subnavli"><a>Water chemistry (3)</a></li><li data-tag="sugar maple" class="subnavli"><a>Sugar maple (3)</a></li><li data-tag="resource management" class="subnavli"><a>Resource management (2)</a></li><li data-tag="throughfall" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Throughfall (2)</a></li><li data-tag="nutrient cycling" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nutrient cycling (2)</a></li><li data-tag="soil chemistry" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Soil chemistry (2)</a></li><li data-tag="soil properties" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Soil properties (2)</a></li><li data-tag="trees" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Trees (2)</a></li><li data-tag="sediments" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Sediments (2)</a></li><li data-tag="pollution" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Pollution (1)</a></li><li data-tag="runoff" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Runoff (1)</a></li><li data-tag="beech" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Beech (1)</a></li><li data-tag="disease" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Disease (1)</a></li><li data-tag="foliage" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Foliage (1)</a></li><li data-tag="urban" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Urban (1)</a></li><li data-tag="plant physiology" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Plant physiology (1)</a></li><li data-tag="rivers" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Rivers (1)</a></li><li data-tag="leaf litter" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Leaf litter (1)</a></li><li data-tag="water quality" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Water quality (1)</a></li><li data-tag="ph" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Ph (1)</a></li><li data-tag="precipitation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Precipitation (1)</a></li><li data-tag="leaf nutrients" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Leaf nutrients (1)</a></li><li data-tag="nitrogen cycling" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nitrogen cycling (1)</a></li><li data-tag="nutrient cycles" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nutrient cycles (1)</a></li><li data-tag="white birch" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>White birch (1)</a></li><li data-tag="snow temperature" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Snow temperature (1)</a></li><li data-tag="bioindicator" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bioindicator (1)</a></li><li data-tag="defoliation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Defoliation (1)</a></li><li data-tag="forests" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Forests (1)</a></li><li data-tag="insects" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Insects (1)</a></li><li data-tag="fishes" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Fishes (1)</a></li><li data-tag="bioaccumulation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bioaccumulation (1)</a></li><li data-tag="balsam fir" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Balsam fir (1)</a></li><li data-tag="carbohydrates" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Carbohydrates (1)</a></li><li data-tag="red spruce" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Red spruce (1)</a></li><li data-tag="snow depth" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Snow depth (1)</a></li><li data-tag="thinning" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Thinning (1)</a></li><li data-tag="forest ecology" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Forest ecology (1)</a></li><li data-tag="streams" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Streams (1)</a></li><li data-tag="species diversity" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Species diversity (1)</a></li><li data-tag="timber harvest" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Timber harvest (1)</a></li><li data-tag="air temperature" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Air temperature (1)</a></li><li data-tag="silviculture" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Silviculture (1)</a></li><li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showAllTags'>Show All Tags</a></li><li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showFewTags'>Show Fewer Tags</a></li></ul>            <li class="navli-toplevel">People</li>
            <a id="clearPeopleFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
            <ul id="allPeople" class="sortButtons people"><li data-people="Don Tobi" class="subnavli"><a>Don Tobi (2)</a></li><li data-people="Betsy Rosenbluth" class="subnavli"><a>Betsy Rosenbluth (1)</a></li><li data-people="Christian Skalka" class="subnavli"><a>Christian Skalka (1)</a></li><li data-people="John Vandenberg" class="subnavli"><a>John Vandenberg (1)</a></li><li data-people="Leah Bauer" class="subnavli"><a>Leah Bauer (1)</a></li><li data-people="Juli Gould" class="subnavli"><a>Juli Gould (1)</a></li><li data-people="Melissa Fierke" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Melissa Fierke (1)</a></li><li data-people="Jerry Carlson" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jerry Carlson (1)</a></li><li data-people="Jeff Frolik" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jeff Frolik (1)</a></li><li data-people="Beverley Wemple" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Beverley Wemple (1)</a></li><li data-people="Jennifer Pontius" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jennifer Pontius (1)</a></li><li data-people="Bruce L. Parker" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bruce L. Parker (1)</a></li><li data-people="William Keeton" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>William Keeton (1)</a></li><li data-people="Allan Strong" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Allan Strong (1)</a></li><li data-people="CJ Langley" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>CJ Langley (1)</a></li><li data-people="Michael Day" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Michael Day (1)</a></li><li data-people="Scott Costa" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Scott Costa (1)</a></li><li data-people="Michael Brownbridge" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Michael Brownbridge (1)</a></li><li data-people="Ethan Angell" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Ethan Angell (1)</a></li><li  class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showAllPeople'>Show All People</a></li><li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showFewPeople'>Show Fewer People</a></li></ul>            <li class="navli-toplevel">Species</li>
            <a id="clearSpeciesFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
            ---
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>
<section class="main-content">
    <article class="search-results">
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <br>
                    <section class="searchResultsBox">
            <section id="search-terms">
                <h2>Search Settings</h2>
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1"><b>Keywords</b>:  <em>test</em><br/></div></div><div class="cf"></div><small id=numResults>( 19 Results)</small><div class="cf"></div>            </section>
            

            
            <div id="all-results" class="result-list">
                       <ul>
                <li data-people=",," data-species=",," data-tags=",," data-theme=",," data-type="person">
                    <span class="hit-type">Person</span> 
                    <span class="hit-title"><a href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/person/test-person">Test Person</a></span> 
                    <span class="hit-score">(Score: 1)</span>
                </li>
            
            </ul>
            </div>
            
    </article>
</section>

</div>
```

```
.hit-title{
    font-size:1.1em;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:3%;
}
.hit-score{
    color:gray;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:.9em;
    width:10%;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
.hit-type{
    padding:4px;
    color:#464646;
    border: 1px solid #008265;
    border-radius:2px;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    font-size:.8em;
}
```

Comment: `result-list` is missing from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the in your code the article is sitting outside the second column you have at md-10. If you place the article inside the column it should work. See code.

```css
.hit-title{
    font-size:1.1em;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:3%;
}
.hit-score{
    color:gray;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:.9em;
    width:10%;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
.hit-type{
    padding:4px;
    color:#464646;
    border: 1px solid #008265;
    border-radius:2px;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    font-size:.8em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Trial.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section class="main-width container">
      <h1>Data Archive Search Results</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <nav id="leftnav" class="sortBar closed">
              <h3 class="spacing">Filter Results</h3>

              <ul class='sortButtons'>
               <li class='subnavli'><a id="all-head" class="all-result-head activeCategory">All Results (19)</a></li>
             </ul>
             <ul>
              <li class="navli-toplevel">Type</li>
              <a id="clearTypeFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
              <ul id="type" class='sortButtons type'>
                <li class='subnavli'><a id="project" class="result-head">Projects (6)</a></li>
                <li class='subnavli'><a id="dataset" class="result-head">Datasets (12)</a></li>
                <li class='subnavli'><a id="document" class="result-head">Documents (0)</a></li>
                <li class='subnavli'><a id="person" class="result-head">People (1)</a></li>
                <li class='subnavli'><a id="news" class="result-head">News (0)</a></li>                
                <li class='subnavli'><a id="event" class="result-head">Events (0)</a></li>    
              </ul>

              <li class="navli-toplevel">Themes</li>
              <a id="clearThemeFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
              <ul id="allTheme" class="sortButtons themes"><li data-theme="forest" class="subnavli"><a>Forest (3)</a></li><li data-theme="water" class="subnavli"><a>Water (2)</a></li><li data-theme="soil" class="subnavli"><a>Soil (1)</a></li><li data-theme="air" class="subnavli"><a>Air (1)</a></li></ul>            <li class="navli-toplevel">Tags</li>
              <a id="clearTagFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
              <ul id="allTags" class="sortButtons filterTags"><li data-tag="foliar nitrogen" class="subnavli"><a>Foliar nitrogen (6)</a></li><li data-tag="ponds" class="subnavli"><a>Ponds (4)</a></li><li data-tag="biology" class="subnavli"><a>Biology (3)</a></li><li data-tag="water chemistry" class="subnavli"><a>Water chemistry (3)</a></li><li data-tag="sugar maple" class="subnavli"><a>Sugar maple (3)</a></li><li data-tag="resource management" class="subnavli"><a>Resource management (2)</a></li><li data-tag="throughfall" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Throughfall (2)</a></li><li data-tag="nutrient cycling" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nutrient cycling (2)</a></li><li data-tag="soil chemistry" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Soil chemistry (2)</a></li><li data-tag="soil properties" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Soil properties (2)</a></li><li data-tag="trees" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Trees (2)</a></li><li data-tag="sediments" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Sediments (2)</a></li><li data-tag="pollution" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Pollution (1)</a></li><li data-tag="runoff" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Runoff (1)</a></li><li data-tag="beech" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Beech (1)</a></li><li data-tag="disease" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Disease (1)</a></li><li data-tag="foliage" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Foliage (1)</a></li><li data-tag="urban" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Urban (1)</a></li><li data-tag="plant physiology" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Plant physiology (1)</a></li><li data-tag="rivers" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Rivers (1)</a></li><li data-tag="leaf litter" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Leaf litter (1)</a></li><li data-tag="water quality" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Water quality (1)</a></li><li data-tag="ph" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Ph (1)</a></li><li data-tag="precipitation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Precipitation (1)</a></li><li data-tag="leaf nutrients" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Leaf nutrients (1)</a></li><li data-tag="nitrogen cycling" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nitrogen cycling (1)</a></li><li data-tag="nutrient cycles" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nutrient cycles (1)</a></li><li data-tag="white birch" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>White birch (1)</a></li><li data-tag="snow temperature" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Snow temperature (1)</a></li><li data-tag="bioindicator" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bioindicator (1)</a></li><li data-tag="defoliation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Defoliation (1)</a></li><li data-tag="forests" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Forests (1)</a></li><li data-tag="insects" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Insects (1)</a></li><li data-tag="fishes" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Fishes (1)</a></li><li data-tag="bioaccumulation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bioaccumulation (1)</a></li><li data-tag="balsam fir" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Balsam fir (1)</a></li><li data-tag="carbohydrates" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Carbohydrates (1)</a></li><li data-tag="red spruce" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Red spruce (1)</a></li><li data-tag="snow depth" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Snow depth (1)</a></li><li data-tag="thinning" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Thinning (1)</a></li><li data-tag="forest ecology" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Forest ecology (1)</a></li><li data-tag="streams" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Streams (1)</a></li><li data-tag="species diversity" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Species diversity (1)</a></li><li data-tag="timber harvest" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Timber harvest (1)</a></li><li data-tag="air temperature" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Air temperature (1)</a></li><li data-tag="silviculture" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Silviculture (1)</a></li><li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showAllTags'>Show All Tags</a></li><li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showFewTags'>Show Fewer Tags</a></li></ul>            <li class="navli-toplevel">People</li>
              <a id="clearPeopleFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
              <ul id="allPeople" class="sortButtons people"><li data-people="Don Tobi" class="subnavli"><a>Don Tobi (2)</a></li><li data-people="Betsy Rosenbluth" class="subnavli"><a>Betsy Rosenbluth (1)</a></li><li data-people="Christian Skalka" class="subnavli"><a>Christian Skalka (1)</a></li><li data-people="John Vandenberg" class="subnavli"><a>John Vandenberg (1)</a></li><li data-people="Leah Bauer" class="subnavli"><a>Leah Bauer (1)</a></li><li data-people="Juli Gould" class="subnavli"><a>Juli Gould (1)</a></li><li data-people="Melissa Fierke" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Melissa Fierke (1)</a></li><li data-people="Jerry Carlson" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jerry Carlson (1)</a></li><li data-people="Jeff Frolik" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jeff Frolik (1)</a></li><li data-people="Beverley Wemple" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Beverley Wemple (1)</a></li><li data-people="Jennifer Pontius" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jennifer Pontius (1)</a></li><li data-people="Bruce L. Parker" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bruce L. Parker (1)</a></li><li data-people="William Keeton" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>William Keeton (1)</a></li><li data-people="Allan Strong" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Allan Strong (1)</a></li><li data-people="CJ Langley" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>CJ Langley (1)</a></li><li data-people="Michael Day" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Michael Day (1)</a></li><li data-people="Scott Costa" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Scott Costa (1)</a></li><li data-people="Michael Brownbridge" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Michael Brownbridge (1)</a></li><li data-people="Ethan Angell" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Ethan Angell (1)</a></li><li  class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showAllPeople'>Show All People</a></li><li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showFewPeople'>Show Fewer People</a></li></ul>            <li class="navli-toplevel">Species</li>
              <a id="clearSpeciesFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
              ---
            </ul>
          </nav>    
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-10">
            <section class="main-content">
              <article class="search-results">
                <section class="searchResultsBox">
                  <section id="search-terms">
                      <h2>Search Settings</h2>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
                         <b>Keywords</b>:  <em>test</em><br/>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="cf"></div>
                     <small id=numResults>( 19 Results)</small>
                     <div class="cf"></div>  

                     <div id="all-results" class="result-list">
                       <ul>
                        <li data-people=",," data-species=",," data-tags=",," data-theme=",," data-type="person">
                          <span class="hit-type">Person</span> 
                          <span class="hit-title"><a href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/person/test-person">Test Person</a></span> 
                          <span class="hit-score">(Score: 1)</span>
                        </li>

                        <li data-people=",Bruce L. Parker,Don Tobi,Michael Brownbridge,Scott Costa," data-species=",," data-tags=",bioindicator,forests,insects,resource management,soil properties," data-theme=",forest,soil,water," data-type="project">
                          <span class="hit-type">Project</span> 
                          <span class="hit-title"><a href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/data/archive/project/forest-ecosystem-management-demonstration-project-carabidcollembola">Forest Ecosystem Management Demonstration Project: Carabid/Collembola population impacts of management practices in high elevation northern hardwood stands: Pretreatment population/soil characteristic</a></span> 
                          <span class="hit-score">(Score: 0.04)</span>      
                        </li>

                      </ul>
                    </div>          
                  </section>
                </section>
              </article>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>

    </section>

      
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When running the snipped, run it at full size screen as it expands to col-10 at medium.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into the css I changed the html in a valid syntax. From here you may move on with your project. Suc6.

```
<div class="main-width container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>Data Archive Search Results</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  <h3 class="spacing">Filter Results</h3>
  <nav id="leftnav" class="sortBar closed">
    <!-- list 1 -->
    <ul class='sortButtons'>
      <li class='subnavli'>
        <a id="all-head" class="all-result-head activeCategory">All Results (19)</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- list 2 -->
    <ul>
      <li class="navli-toplevel">
        <span>Type</span>
        <a id="clearTypeFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
        <ul id="type" class='sortButtons type'>
          <li class='subnavli'><a id="project" class="result-head">Projects (6)</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli'><a id="dataset" class="result-head">Datasets (12)</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli'><a id="document" class="result-head">Documents (0)</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli'><a id="person" class="result-head">People (1)</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli'><a id="news" class="result-head">News (0)</a></li>                
          <li class='subnavli'><a id="event" class="result-head">Events (0)</a></li>    
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navli-toplevel">
        <span>Themes</span>
        <a id="clearThemeFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
        <ul id="allTheme" class="sortButtons themes">
          <li data-theme="forest" class="subnavli"><a>Forest (3)</a></li>
          <li data-theme="water" class="subnavli"><a>Water (2)</a></li>
          <li data-theme="soil" class="subnavli"><a>Soil (1)</a></li>
          <li data-theme="air" class="subnavli"><a>Air (1)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navli-toplevel">
        <span>Tags</span>
        <a id="clearTagFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
        <ul id="allTags" class="sortButtons filterTags">
          <li data-tag="foliar nitrogen" class="subnavli"><a>Foliar nitrogen (6)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="ponds" class="subnavli"><a>Ponds (4)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="biology" class="subnavli"><a>Biology (3)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="water chemistry" class="subnavli"><a>Water chemistry (3)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="sugar maple" class="subnavli"><a>Sugar maple (3)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="resource management" class="subnavli"><a>Resource management (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="throughfall" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Throughfall (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="nutrient cycling" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nutrient cycling (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="soil chemistry" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Soil chemistry (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="soil properties" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Soil properties (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="trees" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Trees (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="sediments" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Sediments (2)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="pollution" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Pollution (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="runoff" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Runoff (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="beech" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Beech (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="disease" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Disease (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="foliage" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Foliage (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="urban" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Urban (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="plant physiology" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Plant physiology (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="rivers" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Rivers (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="leaf litter" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Leaf litter (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="water quality" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Water quality (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="ph" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Ph (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="precipitation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Precipitation (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="leaf nutrients" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Leaf nutrients (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="nitrogen cycling" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nitrogen cycling (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="nutrient cycles" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Nutrient cycles (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="white birch" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>White birch (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="snow temperature" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Snow temperature (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="bioindicator" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bioindicator (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="defoliation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Defoliation (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="forests" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Forests (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="insects" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Insects (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="fishes" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Fishes (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="bioaccumulation" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bioaccumulation (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="balsam fir" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Balsam fir (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="carbohydrates" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Carbohydrates (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="red spruce" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Red spruce (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="snow depth" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Snow depth (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="thinning" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Thinning (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="forest ecology" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Forest ecology (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="streams" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Streams (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="species diversity" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Species diversity (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="timber harvest" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Timber harvest (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="air temperature" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Air temperature (1)</a></li>
          <li data-tag="silviculture" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Silviculture (1)</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showAllTags'>Show All Tags</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showFewTags'>Show Fewer Tags</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navli-toplevel">
        <span>People</span>
        <a id="clearPeopleFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
        <ul id="allPeople" class="sortButtons people">
          <li data-people="Don Tobi" class="subnavli"><a>Don Tobi (2)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Betsy Rosenbluth" class="subnavli"><a>Betsy Rosenbluth (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Christian Skalka" class="subnavli"><a>Christian Skalka (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="John Vandenberg" class="subnavli"><a>John Vandenberg (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Leah Bauer" class="subnavli"><a>Leah Bauer (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Juli Gould" class="subnavli"><a>Juli Gould (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Melissa Fierke" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Melissa Fierke (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Jerry Carlson" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jerry Carlson (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Jeff Frolik" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jeff Frolik (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Beverley Wemple" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Beverley Wemple (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Jennifer Pontius" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Jennifer Pontius (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Bruce L. Parker" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Bruce L. Parker (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="William Keeton" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>William Keeton (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Allan Strong" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Allan Strong (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="CJ Langley" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>CJ Langley (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Michael Day" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Michael Day (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Scott Costa" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Scott Costa (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Michael Brownbridge" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Michael Brownbridge (1)</a></li>
          <li data-people="Ethan Angell" class="subnavli hideMatches"><a>Ethan Angell (1)</a></li>
          <li  class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showAllPeople'>Show All People</a></li>
          <li class='subnavli showLessMore'><a id='showFewPeople'>Show Fewer People</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navli-toplevel">
        <a id="clearSpeciesFilter" class="filter-clear">Remove filter</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="col-md-10 main-content">
  <div class="search-results">
    <br>
    <div class="searchResultsBox">
      <div id="search-terms">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
            <h2>Search Settings</h2>
            <b>Keywords</b>:  <em>test</em><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cf"></div>
        <small id="numResults">( 19 Results)</small>
        <div class="cf"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="all-results" class="result-list">
        <ul>
          <li data-people=",," data-species=",," data-tags=",," data-theme=",," data-type="person">
            <span class="hit-type">Person</span> 
            <span class="hit-title"><a href="https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/person/test-person">Test Person</a></span> 
            <span class="hit-score">(Score: 1)</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

</div> <!--/.row-->
</div> <!--/.container-->
```